# jsf and controller, bean

Tags: java, jsf

I want to learn that if I can define user input parameters at bean class and take these input parameters from a controller function with submit button :

for example input 
jsp :

```
<h:inputSecret value="#{control.userObj.pwrd}"></h:inputSecret>
   <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Giris" action="#{control.check}">
</h:commandButton>
```

"User" bean class :

```
  private String userName;   (with getter and setter)
```

"Control" controller class :

```
 private User userObj;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or are struggling with. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sory, I 'm new to jsf and try to understand what happens :)I want to take the user input value at controller class (from jsp page with submit button)... the variable (read from jsp) can be defined on bean, not controller class?

Comment: Aha, you got a `PropertyNotFoundException: target unreachable, identifier resolved to null` or something when submitting? If you are unable to understand the exception you got, you should include it in your question. Exceptions are namely very important to help understanding the cause of the problem.  We can explain them to you in layman's terms so that you are able to understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using nested bean properties, then you need to prepare it yourself so that JSF can call the setters on it. JSF/EL namely won't prepare them for you.

```
public class Control {

    private User userObj;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userObj = new User();
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way `#{control.userObj.userName}` will work in input fields.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 Hello World - The Model, Controller and View](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheModel)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I defined getter and setter at bean class, I have tried now ; <h:inputText value="#{control.userObj.userName}"></h:inputText> and at controller I create with "new" (as you said) and called " if(userObj.getUserName().equals("seyma"))" and the exception is: javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error testing property 'userName' in bean of type null..

Comment: Then the `#{control.userObj}` is still `null`. So you have not saved the changes or not redeployed the webapp or not restarted the server. Or the `getUserObj()` returns `null` instead of `userObj`. Follow the tutorial link to get started and to grasp the basic concepts.

Comment: ok, thank you for replies, the link will be good to understand :)